# error during running a hive query when I am using alias for table names

Tags: mysql, hive

I ran the following query:

```
select a.cust_id, a.date, b.sum1 as open_spend 
from stone.monthly_data a, input1 b 
where a.cust_id=b.cust_id 
group by a.cust_id,a.date limit 20;
```

I get the following error:
Cannot recognize input near 'a' ',' 'input1' in table source(state=42000,code=40000)

```
I got the error even when I used 'AS':
select a.cust_id, a.date, b.sum1 as open_spend 
from stone.monthly_data AS a, input1 b AS b 
where a.cust_id=b.cust_id 
group by a.cust_id,a.date limit 20;
```

can some-one let me know what is wrong?

Comment: The below query is still giving me error:                                               select a.cust_id, a.date, b.sum1 as open_spend from stone.monthly_data a, pratiti1.input1 b where a.cust_id=b.cust_id group by a.cust_id, a.date, b.sum1;

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing to do with alias, try to give database name for input1 b.

One more thing is b.sum1 is not in group by condition, you may get different error for that one also.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply but I tried giving the database name and changed group by condition also. It still gives me the same error in beeline(HIVE). I cannot think of what else might be the cause.

Comment: Error is a bit different now. Error: ParseException line 1:96 missing EOF at ',' near a1.

Comment: @pratz - pls provide your modified query if the error still exists.

Comment: select a.cust_id, a.date, b.sum1 as open_spend
from stone.monthly_data a, pratiti1.input1 b 
where a.cust_id=b.cust_id 
group by a.cust_id, a.date, b.sum1; -I am running it in beeline/HIVE